# Infinite-valued TQBF

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

The [TQBF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_quantified_Boolean_formula) problem is defined for two-valued logic. Consider a similar problem in a setting of infinitely many truth values.
This is to prevent propositional quantification from being trivially translated away.

While it is well known that multi-valued Boolean algebra without quantification collapses to two-valued,
is this also the case for infinite-valued quantified boolean logics? Does the infinite-valued TQBF problem collapse into two-valued TQBF?

Comment: What do you mean by "multi-valued Boolean algebra"?

Comment: I mean the algebraic structure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_(structure) I can't find the link right now, but the theorems provable from those axioms for the two-element case are exactly those provable using any other set and the Boolean Algebra axioms. So additional truth values do not offer anything.

Comment: Unlike Boolean Algebras, in Heyting Algebras for example we can have infinite number of truth values. I am not sure how to approach the question for quantified propositional logic with infinite truth values. Does it necessarily prove the same theorems as its two valued case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reduction of QBF to propositional logic only works if you interpret the quantifiers as quantifying over the two-element boolean algebra, $\Bbb{B} = \{\top, \bot\}$. Consider the following QBF that says any $x$ is either at the top or the bottom of the lattice:

$$\forall x [(\forall y (y \Rightarrow x)) \lor (\forall y (x \Rightarrow y))]$$

This holds in $\Bbb{B}$, but not in any Boolean algebra with more than two elements. E.g., in the four-element boolean algebra $\Bbb{B} \times \Bbb{B}$, with $x = (\top, \bot)$ and $y = (\bot, \top)$, neither  $x \Rightarrow y$ nor $y \Rightarrow x$ holds.

Without quantifiers, the language of propositional logic is too weak to distinguish between $\Bbb{B}$ and any other Boolean algebra, e.g., $(x \Rightarrow y) \lor (y \Rightarrow x)$ holds in $\Bbb{B} \times \Bbb{B}$ just as it does in $\Bbb{B}$. (To prove the general claim you use [Stone's representation theorem for Boolean algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone's_representation_theorem_for_Boolean_algebras) to embed an arbitrary algebra in $\Bbb{B}^I$ for some index set $I$. A quantifier-free formula that is true in each factor of a product algebra is true in the product algebra.)

Comment: I have some doubt about this now, because a similar argument can then be applied to Boolean Algebras without quantification involved. Perhaps the lattice required for this is incompatible with the Boolean Algebra axioms?

Comment: I don't know what "similar argument" you have in mind. I've expanded the answer to explain why there is no problem with quantifier-free formulas.

Comment: I had something invalid in mind. Thanks. Would you happen to know of the appropriate terminology to search for this more general TQBF problem? Because everything I have found so far is always about the two-valued lattice, including automated QBF solvers. I would like to play with a general QBF solver or at least embed the general QBF info first order theorem prover's logic (Probably another question to ask)

Comment: Try "decidability of the first order theory of Boolean algebras" (which was proved by Tarski, I believe). If you are interested in "internalising" the quantifiers, then try "complete boolean algebras" (which have internal sup and inf operators analogous to the logical quantifiers).

Comment: Thanks. Now I am interested in the decidability of the internalized quantifiers version, I wonder if it ends up stronger. That is the case for intuitionistic QBF, but I wonder if it happens with infinite-valued "QBA" too. I will ask it separately.

Comment: For the first-order theory of Boolean algebras (without quantification), wikipedia has this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_first-order_theories#Boolean_algebras and confirms decidability was proved by Tarski.