# Translation of infinite-valued QBF to first order logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

Quantified Boolean Formulas with infinite values are distinct from their usual 2-valued version ([proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2406421/infinite-valued-tqbf?noredirect=1#comment4970168_2407013)).

Is there a known way to express such formulas in standard first order logic notation (so that they can be fed to a first order logic theorem prover? What I have in mind is some scheme similar to how modal logics (with infinite number of truth values) can be simulated using the so-called Standard Translation into first order logic. Obviously, a direct translation using a single-argument truth predicate assumes two values and is not applicable in this case, the truth predicate involved probably needs two arguments, as in the Standard Translation. I apologize beforehand for the exploratory nature of the question.

Comment: This paper on the [decision problem for boolean algebras](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82421943.pdf) may be of interest.